# How to compare releases to a specific branch?

Tags: github

I notice that in the GitHub “Releases” page there is a handy mention of how many commits have occurred since branch “Develop”. For instance, see this [example from AnkiDroid](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/releases).

[image]

How can GitHub be configured to show how many commits were made to a different branch?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can see the commits and changes between tags if you change the URL to the following format:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repo}/compare/{older-tag}...{newer-tag}
```

This will show you the count and changes of up to 250 commits made between the tags.

So from your example it would be:

```
https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/compare/v2.2beta7...v2.2beta8
```

Similarly if you wanted to compare commits between branches the URL would be like this:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repo}/compare/{branch}...{other-branch}
```

Comment: How to compare if the commit limit exceeds 250 ?

Comment: Until they change it, you can't compare if commits are over 250 @cja

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise is it possible to compare a specific directory between two branches?

Comment: Weird that you have to manipulate the url to get this feature, while all interface elements to provide this feature seem to exist in other places. Still, it works :)